# MVC 5 - SingleOrDefault method not working in ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a Test controller with a simple method:

```
private ApplicationEntities _db = new ApplicationEntities();

public String GetSomeString()
{
    return _db.someStoredProcedure(8).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

This works fine in a controller and say the method returns "Hello"
The problem comes when it's in a ViewModel.
I have simplified it to this:

```
public class TestView
{
   private ApplicationEntities _db = new ApplicationEntities();

   private string smth;

   public String Something
   {
     get {
        //This line does not work here. 
       Error    5   'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult<string>' does not contain a definition for 'SingleOrDefault' and no extension method 'SingleOrDefault' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

        var d = _db.someStoredProcedure(8).SingleOrDefault();

         //This works, since the result is always only 1 row
        var a = _db.someStoredProcedure(8).GetEnumerator();
        var b = a.MoveNext();
        var c = a.Current;
           return a.Current;
        }
        set { smth= value; }
     }

    public async static void getString()
    {
       var a = new TestView().Something;
    }


}
```

Question is why SingleOrDefault() is not working here? (There is no assembly reference that can be easily added) And how this ViewModel and getString method can be solved better?

Comment: `.GetEnumerator().SingleOrDefault()`?

Comment: What type does `someStoredProcedure()` return? Note this should be a method, not a property [Choosing Between Properties and Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229054(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Only methods availible are: Dispose, Equals, GetHashCode, GetType, MoveNext, Reset, ToString

Comment: It returns a string. From the ObjectResult: return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<string>("someStoredProcedure", paraA);

Comment: `using System.Linq;`

Comment: @StephenMuecke The error message suggests it returns a `'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult<string>'`

Comment: Try this link : http://www.devtoolshed.com/using-stored-procedures-entity-framework-scalar-return-values

Comment: You are likely missing a using statement in your view model, try adding `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Ah jeez using System.Linq; worked. Had tried using using System.Linq.Enumerable; but that didn't work >.<

Comment: Off topic a bit, but I would strongly suggest you don't have your viewmodel class perform any database queries. It should be storing the data only, but that's just my two pence worth. Testing code using viewmodels is a lot easier when they don't have a dependency on database contexts, such as your `TestView` class.

Comment: @DavidG Post that as an answer so it can be marked as so.